# Boost Regex not working in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, boost-regex

I don't understand why Boost Regex doesn't work with my current VS 2010 project. On Linux the same code works fine and even in VS 2010 if I create a small project with just the offending code and same inputs it works.

In my project when `boost::regex_search` is called the program crashes and for some reason if I compile the project using `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK`, `boost::regex_search` returns true but the next instruction throws a

```
Attempt to access an uninitialzed boost::match_results<> class.
```

and still crashes for a different reason.
I think it has something to do with default compiler settings but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Posting some code and compiler errors would help.